# Сгорать от стыда или со стыда?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Встречаю разные варианты этого фразеологизма: "сгорать от стыда" или "сгорать со стыда". Логично было бы предположить, что правильнее говорить "от стыда", но употребляют оба варианта.
Скажите, пожалуйста, какой из них более верный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Со стыда" является разговорным вариантом. Более правильный, разумеется, "от стыда", как вы и предполагаете. Однако, "со стыда" уже давно является распространённым фразеологизмом,а стало быть, его использование нельзя считать ошибкой. Окончательный выбор будет определяться скорее характером текста: что-то более официальное, безусловно, должно содержать конструкцию "от стыда", в то время как, скажем, фраза персонажа в книге, вполне себе допускает использование "со стыда".

Answer (score 2):

Начать с того, что "сгореть от [со] стыда" и так является разговорным выражением, так что разницы, думаю, нет никакой.

Answer (score 2):

На Грамоте.ру в толковом словаре: гореть со стыда(испытывать сильный стыд). У Ожегова: гореть  (сгорать) от стыда (испытывать сильный  стыд;  разг).

Учитывая, что этот фразеологизм употребляется в разговорной речи, оба варианта являются возможными, однако частотность употребления "сгорать от стыда" выше, особенно в современной литературе.

Классики использовали оба выражения:

Я сгорела, сгорела со стыда за нашу публику! (Ф. М. Достоевский).

И я, упав на дно телеги, сгорал со стыда и не видел никакого спасения от неминуемого позора (Н. С. Лесков).

Казенное добро таскаешь! Матрос сгорал от стыда. ― Никак нет, ваше высокобродье (А.С. Новиков-Прибой).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказал "сгорал со стыда", но "покраснел от стыда"; "умирал со смеху", но "прослезился от смеха". 
Хочется видеть разный смысл в выражениях с разными предлогами. Возможно, когда-то он и был разным, а предлог "со" указывал на то, что выражение не вполне буквально. Этот предлог выглядит уместным только в идиоматических выражениях, где нет причинно-следственной связи между словами. Например, выражение "сгорал со стыда" (= его жёг стыд) невозможно трактовать как "он сгорал - потому что ему было стыдно", это неделимая метафора. А вот "покраснел от стыда" вполне трактуется буквально (он и в самом деле покраснел по этой причине), причём в сравнении с этим "покраснел со стыда" воспринимается неестественным и просторечным. Аналогичным образом различаются "умирал со смеху" (смеялся так, что казалось, умрёт) и "прослезился от смеха" (буквально, прослезился по причине смеха). В этих примерах просматривается разная функция предлогов: "от" ссылается на причину видимого явления, "со" связывает в общую метафору чьё-то состояние и степень его проявления.

Что касается классиков: не всегда их цитирование позволяет установить истину. В одних случаях своеобразная речь может быть намеренно приписана автором персонажу. А иногда, если нельзя что-то списать на старые языковые нормы... приходится соглашаться с высказыванием одного современного литератора: не все шедевры хорошо написаны.